# How to use CGAffineTransformConcat properly, combine scale and rotate

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, cgaffinetransform

I am creating view, then rotating them and flipping them. Seems to work to use CGAffineTransformConcat to combing the scales and rotation to get the result I expect, but I am running into some trouble.

Initially I set up a transform that flips the view vertically.

```
CGAffineTransform flipViewTrans;

viewFlipTrans = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1, -1);
selectedView.transform = CGAffineTransformConcat(selectedView.transform, flipViewTrans);
```

[image]

When I rotate the view I concat the original flip transform and this seems to preserve this flip transform exactly as expected through the rotation.

```
-(IBAction)rotateView:(UISlider*)sender {
    float angle = sender.value;
    selectedView.rotation = angle;
    [selectedView setTransform:CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(angle)];
    selectedView.transform = CGAffineTransformConcat(selectedView.transform, flipViewTrans);
}
```

[image]

The view flips fine too.

```
-(IBAction)flipSickerH:(GradientButton*)sender {
    viewFlipTrans = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(-1, 1);
    selectedView.transform = CGAffineTransformConcat(selectedView.transform, viewFlipTrans);
}
```

[image]
[image]
[image]

The problem is when I rotate after doing the flip as above, the results do not come out as expected. The view flips in the opposite direction suddenly.

[image]

What is happening, I think, is that the concatenated transforms are reset, so the only transform is the rotation. So the concatenation in the rotate code is failing in this case maybe.

Any clues as to what I need to do?

Comment: I may be tired but I'm unable to understand what problem you are getting from your question. An image or something showing what is working and what is not (actual and expected result) would help a lot since transforms are so visual. P.s. you know that order matters when concatenating transforms, right?

Comment: You're combining two existing affine transforms. Since you flipped the coordinate system, you should rotate -45 degrees. You may also calculate the degree programatically and use rotation with that value.

Comment: If this is the answer could you write it as an answer to the question